# data-sentence in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to perform that after hovering over the image, the text from the attribute `data-sentence` has been displayed (under the picture). I didn't see such an attribute. Can anyone tell me how I can do something like that?

HTML:

```
<li>
  <input id="checkbox_yoda" type="checkbox" name="character" value="light_side">
  <label for="checkbox_yoda" data-sentence="Force is strong in you">Yoda</label>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

label[for=checkbox_yoda] {
    content: url(../images/yoda.png);
}
```

Comment: [Seems to be `content:attr(data-sentence);`.](http://www.dreamdealer.nl/articles/using_the_data_attribute_as_content_in_css.html)

Comment: yea, its good one mate

Comment: I still have a problem with it. Could you show me this on the example of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this way

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

label[for=checkbox_yoda] {
    
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

[data-science] {
  position: relative; 
}

[data-science]::before,
[data-science]::after {
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 1;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
[data-science]::before {
  content: '';
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  z-index: 1001;
}
[data-science]::after {
  content: attr(data-science);
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 3em;
  max-width: 21em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 1ch 1.5ch;
  border-radius: .3ch;
  box-shadow: 0 1em 2em -.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1000;
}

[data-science]:hover::before,
[data-science]:hover::after {
  display: block;
}

[data-science='']::before,
[data-science='']::after {
  display: none !important;
}

/* FLOW: UP */
[data-science]:not([flow])::before,
[data-science][flow^="up"]::before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-top-color: #333;
}
[data-science]:not([flow])::after,
[data-science][flow^="up"]::after {
  bottom: calc(100% + 5px);
}
[data-science]:not([flow])::before,
[data-science]:not([flow])::after,
[data-science][flow^="up"]::before,
[data-science][flow^="up"]::after {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -.5em);
}

/* FLOW: DOWN */
[data-science][flow^="down"]::before {
  top: 100%;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #333;
}
[data-science][flow^="down"]::after {
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
}
[data-science][flow^="down"]::before,
[data-science][flow^="down"]::after {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, .5em);
}

/* FLOW: LEFT */
[data-science][flow^="left"]::before {
  top: 50%;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-color: #333;
  left: calc(0em - 5px);
  transform: translate(-.5em, -50%);
}
[data-science][flow^="left"]::after {
  top: 50%;
  right: calc(100% + 5px);
  transform: translate(-.5em, -50%);
}

/* FLOW: RIGHT */
[data-science][flow^="right"]::before {
  top: 50%;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-color: #333;
  right: calc(0em - 5px);
  transform: translate(.5em, -50%);
}
[data-science][flow^="right"]::after {
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(100% + 5px);
  transform: translate(.5em, -50%);
}

/* KEYFRAMES */
@keyframes data-sciences-vert {
  to {
    opacity: .9;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes data-sciences-horz {
  to {
    opacity: .9;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
  }
}

/* FX All The Things */ 
[data-science]:not([flow]):hover::before,
[data-science]:not([flow]):hover::after,
[data-science][flow^="up"]:hover::before,
[data-science][flow^="up"]:hover::after,
[data-science][flow^="down"]:hover::before,
[data-science][flow^="down"]:hover::after {
  animation: data-sciences-vert 300ms ease-out forwards;
}

[data-science][flow^="left"]:hover::before,
[data-science][flow^="left"]:hover::after,
[data-science][flow^="right"]:hover::before,
[data-science][flow^="right"]:hover::after {
  animation: data-sciences-horz 300ms ease-out forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <input id="checkbox_yoda" type="checkbox" name="character" value="light_side">
  <span flow="down" data-science="Force is strong in you">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
  </span>
</div>
```

And you choose direction via `flow` `right` `top` and so on.....

Comment: `data-science` is an interesting choice. I'd have used with `data-fiction`.

Comment: you can choose your own selector. Its very flexible and interesting to use it.

Comment: Kumar, your code is too difficult for me. I just need a text to be displayed after hover (without animation). Could you help me edit and minimize it?

Comment: Here it is... I have removed all animation and positioning option
https://jsfiddle.net/2Ltdggnx/

Comment: thank you very much. I hope that someday I will reach the level of knowledge that will allow me to understand your advanced code. have a nice day! :)

Comment: Kumar, can you look at my project? https://jsfiddle.net/1tvpxen1/
Please, remember that I can't edit a html code. (
this is the requirement)

Comment: Kumar, this is more difficult than I thought :D I still do not know why it does not work.

Comment: I just add css nothing else mate.. you can compare

Comment: It still does not work well after adding. the problem is with `content` in `label[for=...]`.  After removing content, everything works fine, but I need to add these images from css level (not html)

Comment: About adding images you can use as background from css too.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m59azhn8/ you can do whatever you want.. Now i have use image from css.